# Activate css animation/translation with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am trying to get off javascript animations and use CSS animations instead.  I am currently using jQuery's animation functionality.

I came across [this](http://www.dte.web.id/2011/11/berbagai-efek-transisi-pada-gambar.html#.URgp9fhky7w) website with a bunch of wonderful css animations.  Such as:

```
.demo1 {
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:all .5s ease-out;
  transition:all .5s ease-out;
}

.demo1:hover {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  -moz-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
  -ms-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
  -o-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  transform:translate(0px,-10px);
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to activate these animations programmatically.  So for example, instead of on a `hover`, how can I translate the element by calling `elem.translate()`?

Comment: Seems like this is what you need: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: perfect.  People need to know about it.  Put it as an answer perhaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting what you're asking, but I think you may be under a mistaken impression of what "translate" is on an element. A DOM element has an attribute called "translate", as well as a css property "translate". However, the element attribute ["translate" is just a boolean flag specifying whether the text in the element should be translated in the linguistic sense](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-translate-attribute), it is not a callable function and has nothing to do with the css property.

That aside, there are still plenty of ways to translate an element programmatically. Some other people already gave a pretty good idea of how to do this with jQuery. If you don't wish to use jQuery, you can still add and remove classes manually (same goes for styles).

---

[Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/ilibew/1/edit) I cooked up for class addition/removal. It's pretty straightforward, but here's the relevant code for class modification:

```
.translator {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0px,100px);
  -moz-transform:translate(0px,-100px);
  -ms-transform:translate(0px,-100px);
  -o-transform:translate(0px,100px);
  transform:translate(0px,-100px);
}
...
function move_box() {
  var the_box = document.getElementById("the-box");
  if (the_box.classList.contains("translator")) {
    the_box.classList.remove("translator");
  } else {
    the_box.classList.add("translator");
  }
}
```

By applying the class, the animation will begin (and removing it will reverse it). This can happen as many times as you'd like.

One important note: for this example, I still have the style "transition:all .5s ease-out;" applied to the div before anything happens. This is just a universal default that governs how animation effects are applied to the element. There are a couple of different approaches to this, but for simplicities sake I'm going to just leave it like this.

Otherwise, you can [add the styles directly, like so](http://jsbin.com/ulapud/1/edit):

```
function move_box() {
  var the_box = document.getElementById("the-box");
  set_translate(the_box, 100);
}

function set_translate(e, pix) {
  e.style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate(0px, "+ pix +"px)";
  e.style["-moz-transform"] = "translate(0px, -" + pix +"px)";
  e.style["-ms-transform"] = "translate(0px, -" + pix + "px)";
  e.style["-o-transform"] = "translate(0px, " + pix  + "px)";
  e.style["transform"] = "translate(0px, -" + pix + "px)";
}
```

Nothing too complex here - it sets each relevant element directly by manipulating the styles on the element. As before, it relies on a separate class to specify the transition style.

---

Personally, I think the class addition/removal is far superior. Technically speaking, direct modification of styles is more flexible, but if that's what you're aiming for you probably should use a good library like jQuery transit (as mentioned in the comments). However, if you just want to be able to programmatically apply a few canned effects, modifying classes on the fly is a fine solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the CSS in place, you can trigger it in jquery by doing `$('.demo1').trigger('hover');` to simulate a hover event, or change your css selector from `.demo:hover` to `.class-name` and just add that class using `$('.demo').addClass('class-name');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.css.fn` to apply the css rules.

```
$('.demo1').click(function(){
    $(this).css({
        transform: 'translate(0px,-10px)'
    });
});
```

Or add a class to the element:

```
$('.demo1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('translate');
});


.translate {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  -moz-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
  -ms-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
  -o-transform:translate(0px,10px);
  transform:translate(0px,-10px);
}
```