# push down navigator like win8 metro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-metro

everybody who has worked with widows 8 metro panel knows that when clicking on the arrow appeared on the left bottom of the screen, it will navigate to the applications page which is totally different from the first page.
i wanna do that on my webpage. when user clicks a block it pushes him down to the element related to that block.
is there any Jquery or JavaScript code for that? FYI i searched a lot and find nothing!

Comment: anyone could answer please? it's bad to be stuck

Comment: You want a button that, when clicked, when navigate the user to a certain part of your page?

Comment: just look at the metro of windows 8 please, u will get the meaning

Comment: I think farskid means the start screen in Windows 8.1. There indeed is a button that when clicked - makes the tiled view of the start screen slide up out of view, pushed by a new view sliding in from the bottom with a list of apps. It's essentially about implementing a push transition like in PowerPoint that replaces one view with another.

Comment: Filip Skakun: i exactly mean that, sorry for not making the meaning clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If JS/CSS is in any way similar to XAML - you'd probably want to run some translation animations on two overlaid views as described here: [Activate css animation/translation with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803824/activate-css-animation-translation-with-javascript)

Comment: actually that didn't help, but thanks for recommending my friend

Comment: That question is exactly about moving things with a slide/translate animation. If there is a more specific problem you have - you can comment on that.

Comment: actually i think i solved the problem by finding this link: metroui.org.ua